# Отображение информации при выборе option в select box

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, mysqli

нужно организовать отображение картинки с описанием к нему при выборе option в select box, которое будет выводится слева от select.

Допустим, такой селект. Данные для select box погружаются из базы данных MySQL:

```
<?php
$service = '';
$query = "SELECT service FROM services GROUP BY service";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$service .= '<option 
value="'.$row["service"].'">'.$row["service"].'</option>';
}
?>

<select name="service" id="service" class="form-control action">
<option value="">Выберите тип услуги</option>
<?php echo $service; ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Кстати mysql принимает ссылки? То есть я мог бы для каждого выбора добавить картинку, точнее путь до картинки и описание к этой картинке. Но как это всё вывести я не знаю.

Comment: В общем картинку не надо. Просто вывод описания при выбранном option в select box

Comment: И да ссылки mysql принимает. Только надо учесть что они будут не известного для тебя размера так что делай тип поля TEXT

Answer (score 1):

Серверная страница допустим service.php

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT service FROM services GROUP BY service";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$service = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $service[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($service, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
?>
```

И клиентский JS(я обычно использую JQ буду писать под него)

```
$(function(){
    function selectUpdate() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'service.php',
            async:false,
            success: function(data){
                json = JSON.parse(data);
                $('#service').html('');
                for (i = 0; i < json.length; i++)
                    $('#service').append('<option value="'+json[i].service+'">'+json[i].service+'</option>');
            }
        });
    }
    selectUpdate();
    $('#service').on('change', function(){
        selectUpdate();
    });
});
```

P.S.: Тут только каркас того как делать обновление для select по коду можно дальше реализовать

Comment: большое спасибо! =))